# Unable to create SecurityPolicy with Adaptive Protection in Google Cloud Armor via Pulumi using Python

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, pulumi, pulumi-python

I want to create Security Policy in my Google Kubernetes such that there is Adaptive Protection enabled for the DDoS attacks, on my application layer.

Reading pulumi documents, this is what I came up with:

```
ddos_layer7_defense_policy_name = "ddos-layer7-defense-policy"
ddos_layer7_defense_policy = gcp.compute.SecurityPolicy(
    resource_name=ddos_layer7_defense_policy_name,
    description="Policy for enabling DDoS defence on L7",
    name=ddos_layer7_defense_policy_name,
    adaptive_protection_config=gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyAdaptiveProtectionConfigArgs(
        layer7_ddos_defense_config=gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyAdaptiveProtectionConfigLayer7DdosDefenseConfigArgs(
            enable=False, # enable DDoS defense
            rule_visibility="STANDARD" 
        )
    )

)
```

I read the [official documents](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/compute/securitypolicy/#securitypolicyadaptiveprotectionconfiglayer7ddosdefenseconfig), and while they also denote `enable=True` as the first argument, my local Pulumi library (the one installed in the virtualenv) does not have that `kwarg`. However, when I look at the code, I can see the two flags being very much present.

Still, I get the invalid key error:

```
    error: gcp:compute/securityPolicy:SecurityPolicy resource 'ddos-layer7-defense-policy' has a problem: Invalid or unknown key. Examine values at 'SecurityPolicy.AdaptiveProtectionConfig.Layer7DdosDefenseConfig'.
```

Reading at the source code is not helping either as the signature matches to what I am providing.

This problem is also unsolved by people working on pulumi, such as [this](https://archive.pulumi.com/t/2764528/did-anyone-try-to-configure-cloud-armour-https-www-pulumi-co#62c18e79-b3f0-41d9-bb4f-7e84f8fc483d).

## Update 1: Setting `enable=True` and removing `rule_visibility` produces the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pulumi-gcp provider is derived from the Google Terraform provider.

There was a [bug in this resource](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/12554) in the Terraform provider which meant that it wasn't possible to manage these resources properly because the resource properties weren't being correctly sent to the API.

This was fixed in [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/pull/12661) PR which was merged into [v4.39.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/releases/tag/v4.39.0) of the Terraform provider.

This then propagated to the Pulumi provider in [v6.40.0](https://github.com/pulumi/pulumi-gcp/releases/tag/v6.40.0).

It's likely you're not using `>6.40.0` of the Pulumi provider, which is why you're experiencing this issue. Try upgrading, and then reattempt.

Comment: I installed the latest version, and destroyed the whole cluster. And, it worked.